# SonarJs still shows warning about postMessage cross-domain issue

Tags: sonarqube, eslint, sonarjs

The error message is `"make sure this cross-domain message is being sent to the intended domain"`.

This check rule from [RSPEC-2819](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-2819)

> Authors should not use the wildcard keyword ( *) in the targetOrigin argument in messages that contain any confidential information, as otherwise there is no way to guarantee that the message is only delivered to the recipient to which it was intended.

I assume it demands `*` cannot be used as `targetOrigin`, But It still shows warning when I use intended domain as `targetOrigin` like below:

[image]

Please somebody can tell me how to pass this check,

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This rule detects only if a method `postMessage` is invoked on an object with a name containing `window` in it. Source code: [PostMessageCheck.java](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/blob/master/javascript-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/javascript/checks/PostMessageCheck.java). To bypass it, just assign your `contentWindow` object into different one, like this:

```
var content = this.elem.contentWindow;

content.postMessage('your message', window.location.origin);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but it still doesn't work, even use `window.postMessage('your message', window.location.origin);`

Comment: You cannot use `window` in your object name. Use `content` like I did in example above.

Comment: Hi, @Peska, thanks, your example works, but i still don't understand why i can't use `window.postMessage` like that?

Answer (score 1):

Have faced similar issue in sonarQube. Below fix worked. Just get rid of using window object using directly.

Actual code:

```js
window.parent.postMessage("data", parenturl);
```

Fix:

```js
var content=window;
content.parent.postMessage("data",parenturl);
```